# Large non-linear system of independent equations: Solve sequentially or stacked?

Tags: python, scipy

Say I have to solve for a large system of equations where

```
A_i = f(B_i)
B_i = g(A_i)
```

for many different `i`. Now, this is a system of equations which are only pair-wise dependent. The `lm` algorythm has proven most stable to solve this.

Now, I could solve these either independently (i.e. loop over `i` many `scipy.optimize.root`, or stack them all together and solve at the same time). I'm unsure which will be the fastest, and it's difficult to know generally. I'm having the following arguments for and against:

- The algorythm initially numerically approximates the Jacobian at the provided guess, increasing dimensionality exponentially increases the time it takes to find the Jacobian (speaks against stacking)
- Once the Jacobian is found, most of the updating is linear matrix algebra, and therefore should be faster if stacked.

Does that make sense? My conclusion would in that case be "if solving it takes a long time (bad guess or irregular function), stack them, if it's quick, do not stack".

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand correctly; when you say that they are pairwise dependent do you mean that the full system can be decomposed in a collection of small 2x2 systems? If so, you should definitely opt for solving the smaller systems. If not, can you provide some equations?